# Assigning a JQuery selector based on background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write a JQuery script that appends a div to a div that contains a specific background image.

I've tried using each to look for every div within the page that contains that particular URL then hides and replace it with a div but it didn't work.

```
<div style="background-image:url('images/image.jpg');">first div</div>
<div style="background-image:url('images/image2.jpg');>second div</div>
```

```js
var test = '<div>test</div>';

$('div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("background-image", "url('images/image.jpg')")) {
        $(this).hide().append(test);
    };
});
```

I'm expecting for the first div to disappear and show the word test while second div will keep displaying but all I'm getting is a blank page.

Comment: Your code is *setting* the CSS value of every div on your page. Use `.css("background-image")` to *get* that value... Better yet, use CSS classes...

Comment: You're using the setter of `css()`, not the getter. Also note that URLs retrieved from CSS will be the absolute URL, not the relative path. I'd suggest that if there's any other way you can do this I really would. This is not a very robust way of doing what you need.

Comment: Also note that your second div is missing a closing `"` on the `style` attribute

Comment: i did try this but it only displays both images and nothing got appended (i'm using absolute URL by the way, I'm just using generic relative path for proprietary reason) var test = '<div>test</div>';

if ($(this).css('background-image') == 'images/image.jpg') {
  $(this).hide().append(test);
}

Answer (score 1):

- First, your second `div` is missing a closing quote, so it's not
  valid syntax.
- Next, when you pass two arguments to the JQuery `.css()` method, you
  are setting the value of the CSS property in question. In your case,
  you want to get that value, so you only pass one argument, the name
  of the CSS property you want to get.
- Also, when you append to an element, you are placing the new content as a child within the element you appended to. So, if you hide that element, you won't see the appended content. Instead, use the [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method which places the new content after the first one as a sibling (rather than a child) to ensure you see
  that item.

So, if we correct these things:

```js
var test = '<div>test</div>';

$('div').each(function() {
  // Test the returned value of the .css() call to
  // see if it contains the path of the desired image:
  if ($(this).css("background-image").indexOf('images/image1.jpg') > -1) {
    $(this).hide().after(test);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url('images/image1.jpg');">first div</div>
<div style="background-image:url('images/image2.jpg');">second div</div>
<div style="background-image:url('images/image1.jpg');">third div</div>
```

But, if you just avoid inline styles and use CSS classes, then your solution is just 2 lines of JavaScript. See comments inline.

```js
var test = '<div>test</div>';

// Simply set up your JQuery selector to find only those
// elements that match the class you want to work with
$("div.background1").hide().after(test);
```

```css
/* Set up classses and use as necessary */
.background1 { background-image:url('images/image1.jpg'); }
.background2 { background-image:url('images/image2.jpg'); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Avoid inline styles and use CSS classes instead.
     They are more flexible and eliminate repeated code. -->
<div class="background1">first div</div>
<div class="background2">second div</div>
<div class="background1">third div</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate a page where background images are more permanent while classes are constantly changing that's why I wanted to assign a selector based on background image and not based on class.

Comment: @shoegazer I don't think you understand. The use of CSS classes can be permanently set up on an element just as inline styles can. There's no difference there. But, classes allow for a flexibility that inline styles don't and that's why they are generally frowned upon.

Comment: the situation here is classes are being maintained by a different team and I have no control of changing it (and this team change the classes on a constant basis) that's why I'm trying to find a solution where I can use background image as a selector instead of class.

Comment: @shoegazer I've updated my answer to show both ways. But understand that there's no reason you can't add your own classes directly to the .html document independently of what the other team is doing.

Comment: thanks so much Marcus for helping me. I was actually able to make it work. Here's my code: var test = '<div>some text</div>';

  $('div').each( function () {
    var bgimage = $(this).css('background-image');
    var bgimageurl ='url("images/images.jpg")';
    if(bgimage === bgimageurl) {
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).after(test);
    } 
  });

Comment: what this does is it looks for the div that contains that particular background image then hides the existing div then appends the new div. By using this there is no need for class manipulation which what I was aiming for from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach

```js
var test = '<div>test</div>';
$('.one').hide().after(test);
```

```css
.one {
  background-image:url('images/image.jpg');
}

.two {
  background-image:url('images/image2.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">first div</div>
<div class="two">second div</div>
```

Comment: @Scott Marcus wrote something like me

Comment: Actually, I copied the OPs `append()` without really thinking about that part. I was focused on setting up the CSS. `.after()` is right. +1

Comment: thank you for the answer but I'm trying to assign a selector based on background image not based on class (please read my title)